# Scope name is {{currency}}, how to get specific value in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-view

The scope name is :

```
{{currency}}
```

I coded this in view. the output is:

```
[{"code":"USD","value":"0.00670000"}]
```

I want to get only value USD in front end.

Comment: Try this: `{{currency[0].code}}`

Answer (score 0):

js code

> $scope.currency = [{"code":"USD","value":"0.00670000"}];

Html code

> {{currency[0]['code']}}

or

> {{currency[0].code}}